# How to use sed with a variable that needs to be escaped

Tags: linux, bash, sed, path, substitution

I have a file, and I am trying to use bask to replace all the contents of a substring with a path.

I can use the command:

```
sed -i s/{WORKSPACE}/$MYVARIABLE/g /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MY-JOB/workspace/config/params.ini
```

My `config/params.ini` looks like:

```
[folders]
folder1 = {WORKSPACE}/subfolder1
folder2 = {WORKSPACE}/subfolder2
```

however, when `$MYVARIABLE` is a path, it fails (containing slashes), the `sed` command fails with:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'
```

When I run through it manually, I see that the `$MYVARIABLE` needs to have it's path-slashes escaped.  How can I modify my `sed` command to incorporate an escaped version of `$MYVARIABLE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing saying you have to use `/` as your delimiter.  `sed` will use (almost) anything you stick in there.  I have a tendency to use `|`, since that never (rarely?) appears in a path.

```
sridhar@century:~> export boong=FLEAK 
sridhar@century:~> echo $PATH | sed "s|/bin|/$boong|g"
~/FLEAK:/usr/local/FLEAK:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/games:/FLEAK:/sbin:/usr/FLEAK:/usr/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/server_1/FLEAK
sridhar@century:~>
```

Using double-quotes will allow the shell to do the variable-substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the `$` sign, and use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i 's;{WORKSPACE};\$MYVARIABLE;g' your_file
```